# How to actually configure debugging in CFBuilder

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I have ColdFusion Builder 2.0.0 installed and I am trying to look at the much vaunted step debugging. However, I cannot seem to get it to work as I don't have my site / JRun install setup in the naive way the examples show.

I am using version 9,0,1,274733 of ColdFusion and my configuration is as follows:-

Installed as multi-server version with Jrun here:- c:\Apps\JRun4

application files are here:- d:\websites\my.website.com

web root is here d:\websites\my.website.com\www

core library of CFCs is here d:\websites\frameworks\core which is mapped in CF as core

---

I have read this watched this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/Using/WS0ef8c004658c1089-31c11ef1121cdfd6aa0-7fff.html and this http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/30/CF8-Debugger-Getting-Started and watched this https://experts.adobeconnect.com/_a204547676/p33029638/?launcher=false&fcsContent=true&pbMode=normal but I get stuck at the point after you have configured RDS and you are setting up the server for your project.

[image]

Now I am pretty sure the above is correct, when I move to the next page in the wizard I get the following:-

[image]

Now I as I understand it my Server Home should be c:\Apps\JRun4 and my Document root should be d:\websites\my.website.com

This all looks like it is going to be fine until you actually try and debug when I get

[image]

followed by

[image]

I can confirm that the server is running and RDS is enabled as in the RDS Dataview I can see all my databases.

Any help would be gratefully received as this is very frustrating and the documentation is very lacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a video tutorial as well that you may want to check and see if that helps. http://blogs.adobe.com/anand/2011/01/learn-how-to-debug-coldfusion-applications-using-coldfusion-builder-2.html

Comment: Cheers Hemant.  I was having a similar issue to that which @baynezy was having, and following through the video got it sorted for me.

Comment: Yeah... it worked in my home environment but not in the office environment (as per the issue description).  I don't even get as far as baynezy: I cannot open my RDS views, just getting the "com.adobe.rds.core.services.Messages" message.  And when trying to start a debug session, I get the same.

Comment: the link is no longer available :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the RDS username/password and the "application server name".  If you are using the base instance that was installed when you setup the multiserver install of CF that is "cfusion", otherwise its the name of the instance you are using.

The RDS username is most likely "admin" unless you setup custom users for RDS.  The password is the RDS password you specified when you installed CF.